# Why is my BottomSheetDialogFragment ignoring my app theme?

Tags: android, android-theme, bottom-sheet, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I just started using a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` in my app, however it seems to ignore my app themes. My app uses a dark theme, and the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`  displays with a white background and doesn't use the accent color of my app. This is the only Android component that's behaving like that. Why is that and how to fix this?

```
public class CustomBottomDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    public static CustomBottomDialogFragmentnewInstance(long id) {
        final CustomBottomDialogFragmentdialog = new CustomBottomDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(Keys.ARG1, id);
        dialog.setArguments(args);
        return dialog;
    }

  @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final long id = getArguments().getLong(Keys.ARG1);
        final boolean isLiveStream = PodcastHelper.isLiveStream(podcastId);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);

...

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Show how you implemented the bottom sheet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default theme of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` is not the app's theme, but it's `Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog`.

And the resource of that style them is `R.style.Theme_Design_Light_BottomSheetDialog`, and you can clearly check this from [their class definition](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialog.java)

```
  private static int getThemeResId(@NonNull Context context, int themeId) {
    if (themeId == 0) {
      // If the provided theme is 0, then retrieve the dialogTheme from our theme
      TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
      if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.bottomSheetDialogTheme, outValue, true)) {
        themeId = outValue.resourceId;
      } else {
        // bottomSheetDialogTheme is not provided; we default to our light theme
        themeId = R.style.Theme_Design_Light_BottomSheetDialog;
      }
    }
    return themeId;
  }
```

So, you need to change this to be matched with the app's theme. [Here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/99) are couple of solutions that are provided for this issue on github

Assuming your app's theme is `R.style.AppTheme`:

**Solution 1:**

Credits to [Bloody-Badboy](https://github.com/Bloody-Badboy)

Apply the app's theme within your custom `BottomSheetDialogFragment`:

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View? {
    val contextThemeWrapper = ContextThemeWrapper(activity, R.style.AppTheme) // your app theme here
    return inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper).inflate(R.layout.custom_bottom_sheet_layout, container, false)
  }
```

**Solution 2:**

Credits to [DSteve595](https://github.com/DSteve595)

Override the the default `bottomSheetDialogTheme` style of the `BottomSheetDialogFragment` as mentioned above:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent=".....">
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.YourApp.BottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.YourApp.BottomSheetDialog" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog</item>
  <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet.Modal</item>
</style>
```

For further research, [this](https://medium.com/over-engineering/hands-on-with-material-components-for-android-bottom-sheet-970c5f0f1840) medium article also would make it more clear

Comment: The first solution solved my issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For me also only the first solution worked but the second didn't. @user1026605 was this the case even for you? 
Even though this issue is resolved in the Google issue tracker but the issue is still happening and we have to use the first workaroung

Comment: The second solution solved my issue. Thanks a lot